# Current transducer: no voltage

Tags: current-measurement, current-sensor

I am working on a project that requires non-contact current measurement. I found the LEM [LA 25-P](https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/la_25-p.pdf) active current transducer. I've put the connection diagram from the datasheet here.

My understanding is that putting a current Ip through the sensor results in a proportional current (in this case 1:1000) being generated at pin M. If pin M is put to ground across a known resistance Rm, a voltage difference is produced across Rm.

I've set it up with 30 V across the U+/U- pins (as per the datasheet) and have been able to put ~1 A through the sensor as a test current. The power supply I'm using across the sensor draws ~1 mA extra under this condition, but I can't get a voltage measured across Rm.

I have tried three different Rm values at, below, and above the specified resistance, but have not read any voltage. I also tried putting a multimeter in current mode in series directly between M pin and ground, but nothing measured.

Is there anything I might be missing, or is my understanding of the transducer incorrect? Where might the additional current draw be going other than through the M pin to ground?

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your hookup? Pictures of the setup, your PCB, your cables position, the voltage that you measure in each cable, how you measure the voltage on the resistor (where you place the multimeter's leads?), a proper schematic showing the values of the resistor and voltage(s), (other than the datasheet's scematic) would be nice. Maybe your multimeter cant see the voltage because its not accurate multimeter, maybe the flow of current is on the opposite direction. What does "cant get voltage across RM means?" 0V?

Comment: It looks to me from the [datasheet](https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/la_25-p.pdf) that the sensor requires a supply of +/12V to +/-15V rather than +30V. In other words Rm must be returned to a voltage in the middle of Uc and -Uc. Is that exactly what you are doing?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany That was exactly the problem. Sorry for the late response, took me a second to find a tracking power supply to test it, but thank you so much. To be honest, I don't understand why the sensor would "care" if that voltage is in the middle of the supply voltages. Why would that be?

Comment: @NateStumpff Thanks for the feedback, I've added an answer with an explanation of why this caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [datasheet](https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/la_25-p.pdf), the sensor requires a supply of +/12V to +/-15V rather than +30V. In other words Rm must be returned to a voltage in the middle of Uc and -Uc.

The internal amplifier has to be able to drive the end of resistor far enough to cause enough current to flow through the feedback coil to null the field from Ip.

It certainly can't swing *beyond* the supply rails. It can't even quite get *to* the rails and it may not even be able to get *close* to the supply rails, depending on the design choices they made.

So, for example, if you have the resistor returned to -15V and you happen to have a negative current, the circuit will certainly not be able to balance. Returning it to 0V when you have 0 and +30 is the same thing.